# Minimum value of NewRatio in java heap tuning

Tags: java, performance, heap-memory

I have a process, where I am consuming a very little memory in the old gen space. Due to this a lot of memory is getting wasted. I tried to tune the old gen space using NewRatio parameter but I couldn't reduce it below 1. Even after setting it to 1, there is a lot of space in old gen area which is not being used at all.

Is there any way/config to reduce the size of old gen space without reducing the size of young gen?

Thanks,
Nitin Goswami

Answer (score -1):

You can control the heap size with the following JVM parameters:

-Xmsvalue

-Xmxvalue

-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=minimum

-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=maximum

-XX:NewRatio=ratio

-XX:NewSize=size

-XX:MaxNewSize=size

-XX:+AggressiveHeap

The -Xms and -Xmx parameters define the minimum and maximum heap sizes, respectively. Since GC occurs when the generations fill up, throughput is inversely proportional to the amount of the memory available. By default, the JVM grows or shrinks the heap at each GC to try to keep the proportion of free space to the living objects at each collection within a specific range. This range is set as a percentage by the parameters -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=minimum and -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=maximum; and the total size bounded by -Xms and -Xmx.

Set the values of -Xms and -Xmx equal to each other for a fixed heap size. When the heap grows or shrinks, the JVM must recalculate the old and new generation sizes to maintain a predefined NewRatio.

The NewSize and MaxNewSize parameters control the new generation’s minimum and maximum size. Regulate the new generation size by setting these parameters equal. The bigger the younger generation, the less often minor collections occur. The size of the young generation relative to the old generation is controlled by NewRatio. For example, setting -XX:NewRatio=3 means that the ratio between the old and young generation is 1:3, the combined size of eden and the survivor spaces will be fourth of the heap.

By default, the Application Server is invoked with the Java HotSpot Server JVM. The default NewRatio for the Server JVM is 2: the old generation occupies 2/3 of the heap while the new generation occupies 1/3. The larger new generation can accommodate many more short-lived objects, decreasing the need for slow major collections. The old generation is still sufficiently large enough to hold many long-lived objects.

To size the Java heap:

Decide the total amount of memory you can afford for the JVM. Accordingly, graph your own performance metric against young generation sizes to find the best setting.

Make plenty of memory available to the young generation. The default is calculated from NewRatio and the -Xmx setting.

Larger eden or younger generation spaces increase the spacing between full GCs. But young space collections could take a proportionally longer time. In general, keep the eden size between one fourth and one third the maximum heap size. The old generation must be larger than the new generation.

Comment: probably you should say that the courtesy is from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html